# Jquery issue hiding loading gif

Tags: jquery

In the following code, at first i generate an url. The url is to get a list of data from database as a pdf file. So on clicking the url i am trying to show loading gif till the pdf file is generated. I am able to show the loading gif, but could not hide it after the file is generated. How to hide it.

Jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('#generate').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tx_value = $('#tags').val();
        TFurlpdf = '/path/exportPDF/'+ tx_value;
    });
    $('a#TFpdflink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (TFurlpdf) 
            window.location.href = TFurlpdf;
        $('#dl-spinner').show();
    });
    $('#dl-spinner').hide();
});
```

minimal Html

```
<div>
    <a id="TFpdflink" href="#">Export PDF</a>
</div>
<div id="dl-spinner" class="dl-spinner" style="display: none;">
    <img id="img-spinner" src="static/images/loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
</div>
```

Comment: How do you know that pdf is loaded or not?

Comment: Also, why a click event inside click event?

Comment: @SudharsanS Only when the file is finished downloading.

Comment: @user3844782 Asking same question again, Then how do you know the file is finished downloading or not?

Comment: @SudharsanS after finished downloading the file will be visible in the desired location. only then i will know. I am completely wrong? please help me.

Comment: JavaScript has no clue if the file is downloaded.

Comment: @SudharsanS using Ajax will not help with downloading the file....

Comment: @epascarello please help me solve this. I am new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**Rearrange the code like below**

> Before success you show the loader and after success you hide the loader

```
$(function() {
    $('#generate').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tx_value = $('#tags').val();
        TFurlpdf = '/path/exportPDF/'+ tx_value;

    $('a#TFpdflink').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dl-spinner').show(); 
        if (TFurlpdf) 

    window.location.href = TFurlpdf;
    $('#dl-spinner').hide();                         
        });


    });
    });
```